# How to get tags and categories?

Tags: functions, code, categories, tags

I used the following code to get tags from the post and then simply echo them:

```
$posttags = get_the_tags($post->ID);
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) { 
    echo $tag->name . ', ';}
}
```

Now I need to get the categories as well. My first idea was to simply duplicate the function but isn't there a way to create one single function that'll retrieve both the tags and categories and then have it echo?

Comment: Well, there is `get_categories()` [you could use](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) maybe you can make a function and combine the two to return what you need.

Comment: wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy, $args ) might help to get both tags and categories?

Comment: @sri Why not answer the question and grab some reputation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, You should rather use `get_the_terms`. It runs filters and uses cache, while `wp_get_post_terms` is more internal method.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam we had a better answer, may be?

Answer (score 0):

[`get_the_terms( $id, $taxonomy );`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) is what you're looking for, I guess.

You can pass array as `$taxonomy` param. So this snippet:

```
$posttags = get_the_terms($post->ID, array('category', 'post_tag'));
```

should do exactly what you're trying to achieve.